# How to get the SQL count represented in three digit number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have got a count query which counts the number of records in one column of my table. As it returns an integer value, is it possible to get 3 digit value forcefully like '001' instead of '1'?

Is this possible? How?

FYI I  am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: "HOW TO GET THE SQL COUNT" - quietly.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/nagendraprasad/archive/2009/03/19/formatting-number-to-add-leading-zeros---sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,COUNT(*)),3)
FROM Table
```